# Sort numpy array by row and order matching values based on original array

Tags: python, sorting, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I would like to sort the rows based on first column values. The trouble is the way it is formatted:

Column I am sorting by: 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,etc ->you can see it repeats itself

Basically I want to group the 1s, then 2s, then 3s, then 4s. The ordering of the matching values matter: I want the 1st '1' row to be the first one that appeared in the unsorted array, followed by the one that shows up next, etc. I use this command:
sortedData= myData[myData[:,0].argsort()]

Unfortunately, it doesn't not appear to order matching columns based on the original ordering of the array. Are there certain options I can turn on to enable this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the sorting algorithm used by [`argsort`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) with the `kind` argument.

Use

```
sortedData= myData[myData[:,0].argsort(kind='mergesort')]
```

to preserve the order of the equal items.  ([Merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) is a *stable* sorting algorithm.)

Comment: As per numpy v.1.15.0, select ``kind="stable"`. ``mergesort`` is just for backwards compatibility.  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html