# Python Numpy's argsort duplicate issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

> a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2])

and I'm using argsort function to short this array

> a.argsort()

the result that I got was

> array([ 0, 10,  8,  7,  6,  9,  4,  3,  2,  1,  5, 18, 16, 17, 19, 11, 12,     13, 14, 15], dtype=int64)

While the expected result should be:

> array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 19, 11, 12,     13, 14, 15], dtype=int64)

I have tried also to reduce the array to be less than 16 members and it was working well. Is there something wrong with argsort function?

Comment: As per the docs, use : `mergesort` for kind - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html

Comment: Maybe a better dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26306011/sort-numpy-array-by-row-and-order-matching-values-based-on-original-array

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'm not aware of this kind stuff.